# Find row name in matrix using cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a function that outputs the row name given a cell value? I don't use index and match often so it's not very intuitive to me. Any help is appreciated, would rather avoid VBA.

For example in the image, I'd want the function to output "13" if I have a cell reference value 6/16/2016
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For 1900 date system, if your reference value is in Z1, please try:

```
=INT((Z1-42365)/14)+1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help, however that doesn't work as I have a column of reference value dates that I want to look up through the matrix indicated above

Comment: This is good, much more efficient than an array formula but isn't the constant 42365 if the first date is 12/27/2015 (or 27/12/15 as I would write it) ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your row names are in column A:A and your range to search is B2:O27 and the value you want to match is in Z1, then try this formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MAX(--($B$2:$O$27=$Z$1)*ROW($B$2:$O$27)))
```

It will need to be input as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a standard formula for looking up the row in a 2d array using an array formula:-

```
=MIN(IF($B$2:$O$27=Z1,row($B$2:$O$27)-row($B$2)+1))
```

must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>